# Unable to load styles using MiniCssExtractPlugin in Webpack 4 for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, webpack, sass

I'm using Webpack 4 for Wordpress theme development. I have configured my webpack.config.js to extract css from js files and load them in separate files. But the styles are not getting loaded, either as  or as separate css file.
webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    userSide: "./js/public.js",
    adminSide: "./js/admin.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              outputPath: "dist/images",
              name: "[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

The css files are being created in the local directory whenever I run `npm run dev` but not showing changes in the website.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is how I config my webpack

You can use my setting to see if it work for you

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
```

Add to plugins section:

```
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
```

And rules section

```
{
   "test":"/\\.scss$/",
   "use":[
      "style-loader",
      "MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader",
      {
         "loader":"css-loader",
         "options":{
            "minimize":true,
            "sourceMap":true
         }
      },
      {
         "loader":"sass-loader"
      }
   ]
},
```

Also you may need to inject css to your html using HTML Webpack [plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)